# Does WCF(Windows Communication Foundation) have a Micro Web Service feature?And does it only supported by REST?

Tags: rest, web-services, wcf, soap, microservices

my question is this:

Does WCF(Windows Communication Foundation) have a Micro Web Service feature?And does it only supported by REST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out: [Difference between WCF and Web API and WCF REST and Web Service](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/webapi/difference-between-wcf-and-web-api-and-wcf-rest-and-web-service)

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to use WCF for REST service when you can use Web API? Is there something reasonable?

Comment: I have just started to learn about this subject. I was asked to find exact answer about this regard. If WFC has a micro web service feature, does it supported by REST and SOAP ?